# Fastest way to check matching position of two sequence of equal length in R

Tags: r, string, dplyr, tidyverse

I have the following function, which basically check for percentage of the matching positions of two strings:

```
library(tidyverse)
calculate_sequ_identity <- function(sequ_1 = NULL, sequ_2 = NULL) {
  #   # Two sequs must be of the same length
  # sequ_1 <- "FKDHKHIDVKDRHRTRHLAKTRCYHIDPHH" 
  # sequ_2 <- "FKDKKHLDKFSSYHVKTAFFHVCTQNPQDS" 

  
  try(if (nchar(sequ_1) != nchar(sequ_2)) stop("sequ of different length"))

  
  seq1_dat <- as_tibble(unlist(str_split(string = sequ_1, pattern = ""))) %>%
    dplyr::rename(res = 1) %>%
    dplyr::rename(res.seq1 = 1)
  
  seq2_dat <- as_tibble(unlist(str_split(string = sequ_2, pattern = ""))) %>%
    dplyr::rename(res = 1) %>%
    dplyr::rename(res.seq2 = 1)
  
  final_dat <- bind_cols(seq1_dat, seq2_dat) %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(identity_status = if_else(res.seq1 == res.seq2, 1, 0)) %>%
    unnest(cols = c()) %>%
    mutate(res_no = row_number()) 
  
  identity <- sum(final_dat$identity_status) / nchar(sequ_1)
  
  identity
}
```

With this as example:

```
 sequ_1: FKDHKHIDVKDRHRTRHLAKTRCYHIDPHH
         ||| || |              |           # 7 matches of 30 char seqs
 sequ_2: FKDKKHLDKFSSYHVKTAFFHVCTQNPQDS
```

The matching identity is 7/30 = 0.23.

But I'm not sure if it's the fastest routine. Please advice what's the fast way to calculate. Typically I have millions of pair to check.

Current benchmark:

```
rbenchmark::benchmark(

  "m1" = {calculate_sequ_identity(sequ_1 = sequ_1, sequ_2 = sequ_2)},
  replications = 100,
  columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed",
              "relative", "user.self", "sys.self")
  
)
```

gives me

```
  test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
1   m1          100   2.267    1.000     2.228    0.032
```

Answer (score 3):

The `stringdist` package is optimized for this kind of task.

Yours is a simple use case, you want the string similarity using the `hamming` distance:

```
stringdist::stringsim(sequ_1, sequ_2, method = "hamming")

[1] 0.2333333
```

If you have a lot of pairwise comparisons to make, you can use `stringsimmatrix()`.

Benchmarks - size 100k comparisons:

```
s1 <- stringi::stri_rand_strings(100000, 30)
s2 <- stringi::stri_rand_strings(100000, 30)

bench::mark(j1 = f(s1, s2),
            j2 = mapply(f2, s1, s2, USE.NAMES = FALSE),
            ds1 = mapply(f3, s1, s2, USE.NAMES = FALSE),
            ds2 = f4(s1, s2),
            ss = stringdist::stringsim(s1, s2, method="hamming"))[1:9] %>%
  dplyr::arrange(median)

# A tibble: 5 × 9
  expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
  <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
1 ss          32.63ms  33.81ms    29.5       4.2MB     0       15     0   507.88ms
2 ds2        136.29ms 160.98ms     6.32    17.93MB     1.58     4     1   633.25ms
3 j1         299.08ms  320.9ms     3.12    83.78MB     1.56     2     1    641.8ms
4 ds1        717.85ms 717.85ms     1.39     3.29MB     2.79     1     2   717.85ms
5 j2            1.39s    1.39s     0.721   58.22MB     1.44     1     2      1.39s
```

Functions used:

```
f <- \(x, y) {
  stopifnot((nx <- nchar(x)) == nchar(y))
  colSums(mapply(`==`, strsplit(x, ''), strsplit(y, '')))/nx
}

f2 <- \(x, y) {
  stopifnot((nx <- nchar(x)) == nchar(y))
  sl <- strsplit(c(x, y), '')
  sum(sl[[1]] == sl[[2]]) / nx
}

f3 <- function(x, y) {
  x <- charToRaw(x)
  y <- charToRaw(y)
  stopifnot((l <- length(x)) == length(y))
  sum(x == y) / l
}

f4 <- \(x, y) {
    l <- nchar(x[1])
    matrixStats::colSums2(vapply(x, "charToRaw", raw(l)) == vapply(y, "charToRaw", raw(l))) / l
  }
```

Comment: Base code appears to be twice as fast, though. Maybe there's a `stringi` solution.

Comment: Yes, it's faster on a single comparison, but if you were doing a large number of comparisons then `stringsim()`/`stringsimmatrix()` allow for parallelization so will likely be faster.

Comment: `mapply` is usually quite slow - for a many approach `f <- \(x, y) {l <- nchar(x[1]);matrixStats::colSums2(vapply(x, "charToRaw", raw(l)) == vapply(y, "charToRaw", raw(l))) / l}` would be a better replacement for `ds` - although still slower than `stringsim`

Comment: @DonaldSeinen - thanks - I knew I was handicapping the function somewhat by vectorizing it with `mapply()` but didn't want to make any changes to the body.  I will add your other function to the benchmark.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the instructive benchmark!

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
f <- \(x, y) {
  stopifnot(nchar(x) == nchar(y))
  matrixStats::colMeans2(mapply(`==`, strsplit(x, ''), strsplit(y, '')))
}

s1 <- c('FKDHKHIDVKDRHRTRHLAKTRCYHIDPHH', 'FKDHKHIDVKDRHRTRHLAKTRCYHIDPHH')
s2 <- c('FKDKKHLDKFSSYHVKTAFFHVCTQNPQDS', 'FKDKKHLDKFSSYHVKTAFFHVCTQNPQDS')
f(s1, s2)
# [1] 0.2333333 0.2333333
```

Comment: I was thinking similarly - that will surely be many times faster.

Comment: @thelatemail yeah to be precise around 250 times faster.

Comment: no need for the `mapply` i think? `sum(x == y) / nchar(s1)` where x and y are `strsplit(s1, '', TRUE)[[1]]`

Comment: @DonaldSeinen You're right, we don't need `mapply`, updated. Now its more than 1K times fater than OP.

Comment: I reckon the `mapply` is sensible to keep though as it makes the function vectorised.

Comment: @thelatemail You're so right, let's keep this―rolled back to original.

Comment: why not use `colMeans`?

Comment: @onyambu Thx, doesn't make much difference, though.

Comment: probaby `mapply(\(x,y)mean(x==y),...`

Answer (score 2):

Generally the more you assume about your input, the more you can cut the meat of functions in R. Of note here is that the sample strings contain only ASCII characters.

One approach then is to avoid compare their raw bytes.

```r
s1 <- 'FKDHKHIDVKDRHRTRHLAKTRCYHIDPHH'
s2 <- 'FKDKKHLDKFSSYHVKTAFFHVCTQNPQDS'

f <- function(x, y) {
    x <- charToRaw(x)
    y <- charToRaw(y)
    stopifnot((l <- length(x)) == length(y))
    sum(x == y) / l
}
```

Which is quite fast, but less safe than other answers proposed here. See for example the output of multibyte characters `charToRaw("不")` (`[1] e4 b8 8d`) compared to `charToRaw("5")` (`[1] 35`).

```
f2 <- \(x, y) {
    stopifnot((nx <- nchar(x)) == nchar(y))
    sl <- strsplit(c(x, y), '')
    sum(sl[[1]] == sl[[2]])/nx
}

bench::mark(
    one = f(s1, s2),
    two = f2(s1, s2)
)

#> # A tibble: 2 × 6
#>   expression      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec`
#>   <bch:expr> <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl>
#> 1 one           3.8µs    4.3µs   189066.    2.08KB     37.8
#> 2 two           6.7µs    7.4µs   118876.    3.37KB     11.9
```